# How to speed up writing large byte array to afile?

Tags: c#, hex, byte, filestream

I need to convert a hex string to byte array, then have to write it to a file. The below code gives **3 seconds** of delay. Below  **hex** is an hex string of length 1600. Is there any other way to make this faster ?

```
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {

            FileStream objFileStream = new FileStream("E://CRec Correcting Copy//Reader//bin//Debug//Files//Raw Data//a123.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
            objFileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            objFileStream.Write(stringTobyte(hex), 0, stringTobyte(hex).Length);
            objFileStream.Close();
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

stringTobyte is a metho to convert the hex string to byte array.

```
public static byte[] stringTobyte(string hexString)
    {
        try
        {
            int bytesCount = (hexString.Length) / 2;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[bytesCount];
            for (int x = 0; x < bytesCount; ++x)
            {
                bytes[x] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(x * 2, 2), 16);
            }
            return bytes;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Please tell me where the delay is happening ?

Comment: Why would you create/open/seek/write/close 5,000 times? What would possibly make someone think that's sensible? That's like driving to the store 50 times to get 50 apples! Open, seek, write as much as you want, then close.

Comment: Open stream only once, and write by chunks of few KB instead of one byte only.

Comment: Please, for the sake of all that is holy, tell me that this code was intentionally created as an example of awful code or as an "optimize this code" exercise.

Comment: is hex always empty? The 5000 loop might have something to do with timing... You can put in 1600 bytes of data in a file virtually instantly. So something is definately wrong with your code. Most likely to do with the loop.

Comment: why do you need stringTobyte, when System.Encoding.Ascii.getbytes() will do what you want

Comment: If that code was meant to be a timing example the question is REALLY clueless, because then the question should read "why is it so slow to open and close a file 5000 times". 3 seconds for 5000 timing operations is not slow - that is quite ok. Less than 1 miliseconds per access, including flushing the changes and updating stuff like last time file was read.

Comment: i am sorry..In that loop the file name will not be the same. Actually i need to write it to a raw file , and the path comes like **FileStream(rawdataPath + filename + ".raw", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);**

Comment: So you create 5000 files of different names with the same data?

Comment: No, the data will change. But the length of the **hex** string will always 1600. Because i am buffering the data up to that length in the same string. I done this to decrease the writing frequency.

Comment: @Gladiator: You're not going to be able to open, write to, and close 5,000 files quickly. There's just too much metadata (directory entries, file sizes, etcetera) access and modification involved. It's especially bad because 1,600 bytes is such an odd size, requiring bits of the old page to be read in before the modification can even start.

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking **way** to complicated. First of all, no need for your custom function to convert it to a byte array. `System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetBytes(string)` will do that for you! Also, no need for streams here, have a look at `File.WriteAllBytes(string, byte[])` method.

Then it should look like this:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("E://CRec Correcting Copy//Reader//bin//Debug//Files//Raw Data//a123.txt", new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(hex));
```

or a multiline version, if you insist:

```
string filePath = "E://CRec Correcting Copy//Reader//bin//Debug//Files//Raw Data//a123.txt";
System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
byte[] bytes = encoder.GetBytes(hex);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytes);
```

Comment: voice = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(objCallFields.Payload);
objFileStream = new FileStream(rawdataPath + objCallFields.callID + ".raw", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
objFileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
objFileStream.Write(voice, 0, voice.Length);
objFileStream.Close();
objCallFields.Payload = BitConverter.ToString(list.ToArray()).Replace("-", "");

Answer (score 0):

Wow. For first do this:

```
objFileStream.Write(stringTobyte(hex), 0, stringTobyte(hex).Length);


byte[] bytes = stringTobyte(hex);
objFileStream.Write(bytes , 0, bytes.Length);
```